# How can I run migration on Heroku Cloud databases(ClearDB) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, heroku, database-migration, heroku-cli

I'm facing a problem on databases migration on Heroku .Im trying to deploy my laravel project with mysql databases using clearDB on Heroku. I have deploy my web app successfully on heroku it work fine on pages that has no interaction with databases but the problem is the pages that have interaction with databases would get 500 server error.So it is the problem with databases I think because I haven't run migration but I have already put Config Vars value for clearDB on heroku Config Vars.So I have tried to run migration on Heroku CLI

```
heroku run php artisan migrate --app <app Name>
```

the first two time I run this command Its show an error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schem  a = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

[pic for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDNu.png)

I keep trying to migrate it but after that I got this error that I dont have access to an app.

```
Error: You do not have access to the app laravel-test-demo.
```

`Error ID: forbidden`
but I have already login in heroku cli
[second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu9MO.png)

Comment: "I have already put Config Vars value for clearDB on heroku Config Vars"—how did you provision your ClearDB database? If you did it [via the addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb) you shouldn't be setting any environment variables. ClearDB and Heroku will do that for you. You just need to _use them_.

Comment: "after that I got this error that I dont have access to an app"—your first screenshot shows `test-laravel-demo` and your second one shows `laravel-test-demo`. Which one is correct?

Comment: maybe this can help 

[link](https://just1and0.medium.com/how-to-setup-database-on-heroku-for-your-laravel-application-6a903c2c75c7)